# JScript: How to give focus to popup window

Tags: popup, window, javascript, wsh

I'm making new window this way:

```
var WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WSHShell.Popup("This is popup.");
```

But window appears under another ones. How can I move it to the front?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps this would help:

> WScript.Shell.Popup has an
>   undocumented value for the nType
>   parameter which causes the resulting
>   dialogs/popups to “stay on top” / in
>   foreground, meaning that they cannot
>   be hidden by other windows or dialogs:
>   4096.

```
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup("Message", 0, "Title", 4096);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using 4096 works for popups to "stay on top"

I'm trying to create Popups in Ruby and Watir Webdriver.

I installed win32ole-pp rubygem

I used this in my Code and it works:

require 'win32ole'

WshShell = WIN32OLE.new("WScript.Shell").Popup("Message", 5, "Title", 4096);